# Create group to restart services in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, service, groups

SYSTEM: CentOS release 6.2 (Final)

I am attempting to allow only users of a certain group lets call it **websupport** access to restart 2 services: **mysqld** and **httpd**

**EDIT:** I do not want to give these users sudo access

I have added these lines to /etc/sudoers:

*%websupport ALL=NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/httpd*

and

*%websupport ALL=NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/mysqld*

When logged in as the user and attempting to run:

*/etc/init.d/httpd restart*

I get this result:

> rm: cannot remove '/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid': Permission Denied [FAILED]
>   rm: cannot remove '/var/lock/subsys/httpd' : Permission Denied
>   rm: cannot remove '/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid' : Permission Denied
>   Starting httpd: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for wssapache
>   httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
>   (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>   (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   Unable to open logs                                              [FAILED]

When attempting to run:

*/etc/init.d/mysqld restart*

I get this result:

> cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permission denied
>   Stopping mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
>   Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]

Answer (score 6):

The entries in  your sudoers look ok. What you need to so is use sudo to run the command e.g.

```
sudo etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

and

```
sudo etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

You can combine the entries in sudoers too

```
%websupport ALL=NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/mysqld, /etc/init.d/httpd
```

Comment: The point is to NOT give them sudo access and only give them access to restart/stop/start those services

Comment: @Phickey: You are misunderstanding the way sudo works. Using the scheme you outline and sudo they will only have access to the commands listed,

Comment: @lain: you are totally right. Just worked like you said.  Thanks!